# Copy chrome session from one computer to the other

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, session-restore

I have just installed chrome on a new computer. I have copied the AppData\Local\Google\ folder from the old machine to the new. Things like bookmarks and history restore, however my previous session doesn't (I have it set to restore last tabs upon restart). To my knowledge this is either saved in the "Last Session", "Last Tabs", "Current Session", or "Current Tabs" files within The AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default folder (my reason for this belief is that deleting these files prevents it from restoring the last session).

Is there a step I am missing here?

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using Chrome's built-in sync feature (sign into Chrome & go to "Settings/Google Dashboard" or "Settings/Advanced Sync Settings") to sync everything?

Comment: @HighTechGeek yes, long story.

Comment: Do tell. It always helps us help you if you tell us what you're trying to do and give us more info rather than less.

Comment: @HighTechGeek basically in a nutshell, these computers aren't always used to connect to websites that are on the Internet. They're actually rarely connected to the Internet. The mainly are used for intranet sites. The session restore functionality still works fine, but I can't sync with my google account because they can't access it.

Comment: @HighTechGeek also it would be against company policy for me to use a google account like this

Comment: So I've narrowed it down to chrome detecting that you have done this, and so it freaks out and doesn't re open your session. If you look in settings it will say it has detected something external (in this case you) have altered the settings, and it has reset some of them. I'm looking into a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Bookmarks are transferring...

1. On the old machine, right-click a tab and choose "Bookmark all tabs...". Give the folder a name.
2. On the new PC, after the Bookmarks have transferred, right click this new folder and choose "open all bookmarks"
3. (optional) Delete the bookmark folder

Comment: That kinda works, however it doesn't restore the history of each tab.